# How to fix foreach loop in function with many getElementsByClassName arguments

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api

The function below is working only for the first Post(post image left) since the commentValue is taking [0].
I tried to fix the function but I'm still getting an error: ***thecomment is undefined.***

[image]

```
function AddComment(postId) {
    let commentValue = document.getElementsByClassName("thisIsTheComment")[0];
    var comment = commentValue.value;
    if (comment != null || comment.trim() != "") {
        var data = {
            PostId: postId,
            Comment: comment
        };
        var url = "https://localhost:44374/Comment/AddComment";
        axios.post(url, data)
            .then(function (response) {
                commentValue.value = "";
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }
}
```

#Second attempt:

```
function AddComment(postId) {
    let commentValues = document.getElementsByClassName("thisIsTheComment");
    for(var comment in commentValues) {
        var thecomment = comment.value;
        if (thecomment != null || thecomment.trim() != "") {
            var data = {
                PostId: postId,
                Comment: thecomment
            };
            var url = "https://localhost:44374/Comment/AddComment";
            axios.post(url, data)
                .then(function (response) {
                    thecomment.value = "";
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                })
        }
    }
}
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="comment-form">
     <input type="text" name="theComment" class="thisIsTheComment comment-input" placeholder="Add a comment..." required/>
     <button type="submit" class="btnaddcomment color" id="btn_comment" onclick="AddComment(@post.Id)" ><i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
</div>
```

How can I fix the function, so I can be able to write comment for each post.

Comment: The OP needs to handle the e.g. 'click'/'submit' event for each comment field separately. Thus an approach was to write ... `document.querySelectorAll('.thisIsTheComment').forEach(elm => elm.addEventListener('click', AddComment))` ... whereas `AddComment` needs to be changed towards handling the value change of the passed `event` object's `currentTarget`.

Comment: Abdullukh pointed the right mistake where I made. However, I have to find a different approach, because (if thecomment != '') wasn't there. It will take all inputs even they are empty and will post them.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `for in` in which element is a string

```
   for(var comment in commentValues) {
        var thecomment = comment.value;
```

Use `for of`

```
   for(var comment of commentValues) {
      var thecomment = comment.value;
```